# java.net.SocketTimeoutException thrown only on some Android devices

Tags: android, okhttp

I am trying to upload a JPEG image file from an Android device. I am using the `square/okhttp` library for creating a request. I am facing this issue on the Lenovo Yoga tablet, that when I am trying to upload the image, it gets the below exception. But when I run the same code on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10", it all works fine and the image gets uploaded successfully.

The camera captures the image and stores it at /storage/emulated/0/ from where the app will pick up the image and try to upload it. I have a service running in the background that does the upload.

```
final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE_JPEG = MediaType.parse("image/jpeg");

        File file = new File(path);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(baseUrl)
                .addHeader("timestamp", map.get("timestamp"))
                .addHeader("Content-Type", map.get("Content-Type"))
                .post(RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE_JPEG, file))
                .build();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Exception:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
11-27 15:37:06.394 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
W/System.err: at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2
Stream.java:593)
11-27 15:37:06.394 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
W/System.err: at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut(Http2Stream.java:601)
11-27 15:37:06.394 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
W/System.err: at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeResponseHeaders(Http2Stream.java:146)
11-27 15:37:06.394 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
W/System.err: at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http2Codec.java:125)
11-27 15:37:06.394 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
11-27 15:37:06.394 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
11-27 15:37:06.394 1770-2339/commyapp.app.debug 
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
11-27 15:37:06.394 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
11-27 15:37:06.394 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
11-27 15:37:06.395 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
11-27 15:37:06.395 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
 11-27 15:37:06.395 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
 11-27 15:37:06.395 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
11-27 15:37:06.395 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
11-27 15:37:06.395 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
 11-27 15:37:06.395 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
  W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
11-27 15:37:06.395 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
11-27 15:37:06.395 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
  11-27 15:37:06.395 1770-2339/com.myapp.app.debug 
  W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
```

Comment: Timeout based exceptions are quite unpredictable. It does not entirely depend on the hardware, but also on internal configurations as well.

Comment: @HiteshPamnani: which internal configurations you mean ?

Comment: I meant the same thing as Prokash Sarkar was trying to point out here. Internal configurations meant the network settings for each device.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to increase the read/write timeout on the server end. A temporary workaround for Android would be increasing the default timeout for OkHttp3 client:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
```

Comment: thanks it worked. Its strange that it was working on some devices and not others. But setting the timeout value surely did work.

Comment: Exceptions for timeout is unpredictable. Some device may process the network call faster while others will take longer time. It's safe to put some extra time on network client so that you don't get run out of time.